# How can I create a custom PropertyDrawer for my Point struct?

Tags: unity, serialization

I created a `Point` struct:

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

I am trying to create a property drawer for it, so that when it shows in the inspector, it is shown in a `Vector2` field.  I have the following script in the "Editor" folder:

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Point))]
public class PointEditor : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.Vector2Field(position, label, property.vector2Value);
    }
}
```

It shows up in the inspector the way I want, but the values are locked at 0. Basically, I am trying to access the `Point` instance from inside the `OnGUI` method, but this could be the completely wrong approach. How can I make this so that when the values are changed in the inspector, the respective `Point` is also changed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason that you can't change any of the values is because the `Point` struct isn't a `Vector2` data type. A `Vector2` contains 2 floats where `Point` has 2 ints, meaning that the types are incompatible. The other problem was that you couldn't get the data from the struct in the way that Unity's inspector code wants you too.

**Point.cs**

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct Point
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

It took me a while to format it the same way that `Vector2`, it's a lot of code but is mostly there to get the correct formatting.

**PointDrawer.cs:**

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Point))]
public class PointDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    SerializedProperty X, Y;
    string name;
    bool cache = false;

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (!cache)
        {
            //get the name before it's gone
            name = property.displayName;

            //get the X and Y values
            property.Next(true);
            X = property.Copy();
            property.Next(true);
            Y = property.Copy();

            cache = true;
        }

        Rect contentPosition = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, new GUIContent(name));

        //Check if there is enough space to put the name on the same line (to save space)
        if (position.height > 16f)
        {
            position.height = 16f;
            EditorGUI.indentLevel += 1;
            contentPosition = EditorGUI.IndentedRect(position);
            contentPosition.y += 18f;
        }

        float half = contentPosition.width / 2;
        GUI.skin.label.padding = new RectOffset(3, 3, 6, 6);

        //show the X and Y from the point
        EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 14f;
        contentPosition.width *= 0.5f;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

        // Begin/end property & change check make each field
        // behave correctly when multi-object editing.
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(contentPosition, label, X);
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            int newVal = EditorGUI.IntField(contentPosition, new GUIContent("X"), X.intValue);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                X.intValue = newVal;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();

        contentPosition.x += half;

        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(contentPosition, label, Y);
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
            int newVal = EditorGUI.IntField(contentPosition, new GUIContent("Y"), Y.intValue);
            if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
                Y.intValue = newVal;
        }
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return Screen.width < 333 ? (16f + 18f) : 16f;
    }
}
```

It looks like this when compared to the `Vector2` type (as requested). Just swap the relevant parts of your code with this and it will let you change the values and keep them persistent throughout their use :)

[image]

Comment: You can avoid making changes to the Point class by using SerializedProperty.Next(true) to step through the x and y int members directly.

Comment: I tried that but when saving it to a local copy it shadow copies, so you only get a reference, when you then go to the next variable the first one gets changed too.

Comment: I've verified this works with `var childProperty = property.Copy(); chilProperty.Next(true);...` then we keep our original `property` as-is for when we want to write any changes back to it.

Comment: ahh, .copy That would solve the it. I'll change the code around and update the answer

Comment: I didn't find I needed SerializeField on the x & y - in my tests they came through just for being public members of a Serializable struct. Also, in a quick test this doesn't seem to work correctly for multi-object editing at the moment. Throwing an EditorGUI.BeginProperty / BeginChangeCheck around each of the int fields and assigning only if EndChangeCheck returns true seems to fix it. I can add that in an edit if you like.

Comment: I did it that way because i wanted to preserve the scroll ability that the vector2 has (not sure if it works your way, if it does go for it).

Comment: Scrollability works both ways, so I've made the edits above.

Comment: This script has a bug. I created a list of objects, and each one of them had a field for this struct. The bug is, that when I edit one object, other objects get updated too! Exteremely bad behavior! I think the problem is the "caching" - when removed, only the proper field gets updated.

Comment: @wilczarz if you go to the post and click on the edited by link and scroll to the bottom where the first edition of this post is, try the `PointDrawer.cs` code from there and see if it fixes it. I don't have unity to test with atm. Report back :)

Comment: I was also having some trouble with this method working in a list. I posted the solution I ended up going with in case anybody finds it useful.

Comment: You sir are a genius! +1    :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried using the solution in the accepted answer but was having some issues with it, particularly when it was being used within a list. After messing around with things a bit and trying out different approaches, this is what I ended up settling on. I'm using the same property drawer for several different vector type structures (works well for any class with 2-4 fields each having a 1 character name).

```
/// <summary>
/// A custom property drawer for vectors type structures.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="UnityEditor.PropertyDrawer" />
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector2i))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector2d))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector3i))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector3d))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Vector4d))]
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Quaterniond))]
public class VectorPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A dictionary lookup of field counts keyed by class type name.
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _fieldCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the GUI is drawn.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="position">Rectangle on the screen to use for the property GUI.</param>
    /// <param name="property">The SerializedProperty to make the custom GUI for.</param>
    /// <param name="label">The label of this property.</param>
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        var fieldCount = GetFieldCount(property);

        Rect contentPosition = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, label);

        EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 14f;
        float fieldWidth = contentPosition.width / fieldCount;
        bool hideLabels = contentPosition.width < 185;
        contentPosition.width /= fieldCount;

        using (var indent = new EditorGUI.IndentLevelScope(-EditorGUI.indentLevel))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (!property.NextVisible(true))
                {
                    break;
                }

                label = EditorGUI.BeginProperty(contentPosition, new GUIContent(property.displayName), property);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(contentPosition, property, hideLabels ? GUIContent.none : label);
                EditorGUI.EndProperty();

                contentPosition.x += fieldWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the field count for the specified property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">The property for which to get the field count.</param>
    /// <returns>The field count of the property.</returns>
    private static int GetFieldCount(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        int count;
        if (!_fieldCounts.TryGetValue(property.type, out count))
        {
            var children = property.Copy().GetEnumerator();
            while (children.MoveNext())
            {
                count++;
            }

            _fieldCounts[property.type] = count;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried doing this?

```
property.vector2Value = EditorGUI.Vector2Field(position, label, property.vector2Value);
```

Basically, `EditorGUI.Vector2Field()` is a function that returns a value of the 
"position". By setting "position" variable to `EditorGUI.Vector2Field`, you'll be able to change the "position" variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What do you mean? Does the script above return a compile error? Also, the first code snippet in your question section, is that all there is to it? Or there is something else?

Comment: That's all there is to my Point struct. There is no Vector2 value.